# Self-modifying program: Why does it raise an exception?

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

Just for the purposes of experimenting and playing around, I wrote the following short x64 assembly program:

```
.code
AsmFun proc
    mov rax, MyLabel
    mov byte ptr [rax], 0C3h    ; C3 is x64 machine code for "ret"
MyLabel:
    mov rax, 239847             ; This isn't "ret"
AsmFun endp
end
```

(I then called the code from C.)

It compiles/assembles/links just fine, but when I walk through the program, Visual Studio complains that an un-handled exception has been raised:  "Access writing violation as [MyLabel].", where of course it doesn't actually say "[MyLabel]", but rather the address that happens to be at in memory.

Why is this happening?  Is it a Windows thing that was put in place to avoid security exploits?

Comment: No, it's an OS thing: code segments are usually assigned to read-only memory.  You can read about the Windows "PE" format here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

Comment: @paulsm4: To be more precise, code pages are mapped read only. You can change the protection if needed for self-modifying code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How do I change this protection?

Comment: You can use [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Good documentation is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127904). You can use [PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz aren't code pages mapped only mapped readonly if the 'writable' bit of the section the page belongs to is 0 in the section headers of the PE file?

Comment: This is an old article, but it gives you the gist of changing your code page(s) to be "writable": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127904.  It uses VirtualProtect.  Here's a tutorial that also illustrates the concept: http://thelegendofrandom.com/blog/archives/1424

Comment: As I recall the read and executable bits are part of the memory selectors. So whenever one of the cs, ds, es, fs, gs or ss registers are loaded a new selector descriptor defining the properties of the memory area is loaded as well. Other properties defined in the descriptor could be the memory area's base address and size. Selector descriptors may be found in the global, interrupt and local descriptor tables (gdt, idt and ldt). The gdt and idt are typically used by the OS, the ldt by the application

Answer (score 0):

I live in Linux world, but perhaps you can adapt what I've found out.

Memory pages are generally read-only if they have execute permission. How I got around this was with mmap() and mprotect()... I'm sure there's something similar in Windows. It's a good bet the Mono source code would shed some light.

I used mmap() to allocate a new page with write access (but not read or execute). I populated it, then called mprotect() to change it to read-only and executable.

Don't forget... there are registers you want to avoid trashing. See the ABI documentation for further details.